# Add wishlist to my dashboard (customer_account_index)

Tags: magento-2.1, custom-options, xml, wishlist, dashboard

I want to add the wishlist in my dashboard in the customer account. Problem is I have to make a new block like this.

```
<block class="Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template" name="customer_account_dashboard_wishlist" as="wishlisting" template="account/dashboard/wishlisting.phtml" cacheable="false"/>
```

and then add a new file `wishlisting.phtml` in the account/dashboard. In the file I have copy pasted the code of original wishlist from this address `module_wishlist>view>frontend>templates>item>list.phtml`

but still, i am unable to have the wishlist in the account. Anybody can help me in this regard. actually, I did not know how XML works in Magento.