# How can I show wish list product in dashboard on account pages?

Tags: magento2, magento-2.1, magento-2.1.7

I want to add wishlist block of customer on My Dashboard after Account Information. How can I do this ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this via layout  files:

create `customer_account.xml`  if not exits at at

> app/design/frontend/{VendorName}/{Theme}/Magento_WishList/layout

Then

**Add code:**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <body>
        <referenceContainer name="content">
            <block class="Magento\Wishlist\Block\Customer\Wishlist" name="customer.wishlist" template="view.phtml" cacheable="false" >
                <block class="Magento\Wishlist\Block\Rss\Link" name="wishlist.rss.link" template="rss/wishlist.phtml"/>
                <block class="Magento\Wishlist\Block\Customer\Wishlist\Items" name="customer.wishlist.items" as="items" template="item/list.phtml" cacheable="false">
                    <block class="Magento\Wishlist\Block\Customer\Wishlist\Item\Column\Image" name="customer.wishlist.item.image" template="item/column/image.phtml" cacheable="false"/>
                    <block class="Magento\Wishlist\Block\Customer\Wishlist\Item\Column\Info" name="customer.wishlist.item.name" template="item/column/name.phtml" cacheable="false"/>
                    <block class="Magento\Wishlist\Block\Customer\Wishlist\Item\Column\Cart" name="customer.wishlist.item.price" template="item/column/price.phtml" cacheable="false">
                        <block class="Magento\Catalog\Pricing\Render" name="product.price.render.wishlist">
                            <arguments>
                                <argument name="price_render" xsi:type="string">product.price.render.default</argument>
                                <argument name="price_type_code" xsi:type="string">wishlist_configured_price</argument>
                                <argument name="price_label" xsi:type="boolean">false</argument>
                                <argument name="zone" xsi:type="string">item_list</argument>
                            </arguments>
                        </block>
                        <block class="Magento\Wishlist\Block\Customer\Wishlist\Item\Options" name="customer.wishlist.item.options" cacheable="false"/>
                    </block>
                    <block class="Magento\Wishlist\Block\Customer\Wishlist\Item\Column\Actions" name="customer.wishlist.item.inner" template="item/column/actions.phtml" cacheable="false">
                        <arguments>
                            <argument name="css_class" xsi:type="string">product-item-inner</argument>
                        </arguments>
                        <block class="Magento\Wishlist\Block\Customer\Wishlist\Item\Column\Comment" name="customer.wishlist.item.comment" template="item/column/comment.phtml" cacheable="false">
                            <arguments>
                                <argument name="title" translate="true" xsi:type="string">Product Details and Comment</argument>
                            </arguments>
                        </block>
                        <block class="Magento\Wishlist\Block\Customer\Wishlist\Item\Column\Cart" name="customer.wishlist.item.cart" template="item/column/cart.phtml" cacheable="false">
                            <arguments>
                                <argument name="title" translate="true" xsi:type="string">Add to Cart</argument>
                            </arguments>
                        </block>

                        <block class="Magento\Wishlist\Block\Customer\Wishlist\Item\Column\Actions" name="customer.wishlist.item.actions" template="item/column/actions.phtml" cacheable="false">
                            <arguments>
                                <argument name="css_class" xsi:type="string">product-item-actions</argument>
                            </arguments>
                            <block class="Magento\Wishlist\Block\Customer\Wishlist\Item\Column\Edit" name="customer.wishlist.item.edit" template="item/column/edit.phtml" before="-" cacheable="false"/>
                            <block class="Magento\Wishlist\Block\Customer\Wishlist\Item\Column\Remove" name="customer.wishlist.item.remove" template="item/column/remove.phtml" cacheable="false"/>
                        </block>
                    </block>
                </block>
                <container name="customer.wishlist.buttons" as="control_buttons" label="Wishlist Control Buttons">
                    <block class="Magento\Wishlist\Block\Customer\Wishlist\Button" name="customer.wishlist.button.update" template="button/update.phtml" cacheable="false"/>
                    <block class="Magento\Wishlist\Block\Customer\Wishlist\Button" name="customer.wishlist.button.share" template="button/share.phtml" cacheable="false"/>
                    <block class="Magento\Wishlist\Block\Customer\Wishlist\Button" name="customer.wishlist.button.toCart" template="button/tocart.phtml" cacheable="false"/>
                </container>
            </block>
        </referenceContainer>
    </body>
</page>
```

If `customer_account.xml`  is exits  at

> app/design/frontend/{VendorName}/{Theme}/Magento_WishList/layout

**Then  add below code under body tab `<body></body>`**

product.price.render.default
                            wishlist_configured_price
                            false
                            item_list
                        
                    
                    
                
                
                    
                        product-item-inner
                    
                    
                        
                            Product Details and Comment
                        
                    
                    
                        
                            Add to Cart

```
                <block class="Magento\Wishlist\Block\Customer\Wishlist\Item\Column\Actions" name="customer.wishlist.item.actions" template="item/column/actions.phtml" cacheable="false">
                    <arguments>
                        <argument name="css_class" xsi:type="string">product-item-actions</argument>
                    </arguments>
                    <block class="Magento\Wishlist\Block\Customer\Wishlist\Item\Column\Edit" name="customer.wishlist.item.edit" template="item/column/edit.phtml" before="-" cacheable="false"/>
                    <block class="Magento\Wishlist\Block\Customer\Wishlist\Item\Column\Remove" name="customer.wishlist.item.remove" template="item/column/remove.phtml" cacheable="false"/>
                </block>
            </block>
        </block>
        <container name="customer.wishlist.buttons" as="control_buttons" label="Wishlist Control Buttons">
            <block class="Magento\Wishlist\Block\Customer\Wishlist\Button" name="customer.wishlist.button.update" template="button/update.phtml" cacheable="false"/>
            <block class="Magento\Wishlist\Block\Customer\Wishlist\Button" name="customer.wishlist.button.share" template="button/share.phtml" cacheable="false"/>
            <block class="Magento\Wishlist\Block\Customer\Wishlist\Button" name="customer.wishlist.button.toCart" template="button/tocart.phtml" cacheable="false"/>
        </container>
    </block>
</referenceContainer>
```

Comment: this works for me but i have a question . How my dashboard know to add this on `my dashboard`. because in the `customer_account_index` in `customer_module` there are only three blocks. orders, info and address. How this knows that wishlist should be added too.

Comment: i have also asked the same question [here](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/196648/add-wishlist-to-my-dashboard-customer-account-index)

Comment: little bit busy now, reply you when i will free

Comment: sure i am waiting for our response. This would be help me in getting out lot of problems regarding magento.

Comment: waiting for your response. can you please guide me in this regard?

Comment: i have a question please can you help me ? i have added the wishlist but it is appearing on all the account pages. what i want was actually to appear it on in the account dashboard page.